# python pexpect sendcontrol key characters

Tags: python, key, character, pexpect

I am working with pythons pexpect module to automate tasks, I need help in figuring out key characters to use with sendcontrol. how could one send the controlkey ENTER ? and for future reference how can we find the key characters?

here is the code i am working on.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pexpect

id = pexpect.spawn ('ftp 192.168.3.140')

id.expect_exact('Name')

id.sendline ('anonymous')

id.expect_exact ('Password')
*# Not sure how to send the enter control key
id.sendcontrol ('???')* 

id.expect_exact ('ftp')

id.sendline ('dir')

id.expect_exact ('ftp')

lines = id.before.split ('\n')

for line in lines :
        print line
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**pexpect** has no `sendcontrol()` method.  In your example you appear to be trying to send an empty line.  To do that, use:

```
    id.sendline('')
```

If you need to send real control characters then you can `send()` a string that contains the appropriate character value.  For instance, to send a control-C you would:

```
    id.send('\003')
```

or:

```
    id.send(chr(3))
```

*Responses to comment #2:*

Sorry, I typo'ed the module name -- now fixed.  More importantly, I was looking at old documentation on noah.org instead of the [latest documentation at SourceForge](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html).  The newer documentation does show a `sendcontrol()` method.  It takes an argument that is either a letter (for instance, `sendcontrol('c')` sends a control-C) or one of a variety of punctuation characters representing the control characters that don't correspond to letters.  But really `sendcontrol()` is just a convenient wrapper around the `send()` method, which is what `sendcontrol()` calls after after it has calculated the actual value that you want to send.  You can read the source for yourself at [line 973 of this file](http://pexpect.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pexpect/trunk/pexpect/pexpect.py?revision=521&view=markup).

I don't understand why `id.sendline('')` does not work, especially given that it apparently works for sending the user name to the spawned **ftp** program. If you want to try using `sendcontrol()` instead then that would be either:

```
    id.sendcontrol('j')
```

to send a Linefeed character (which is control-j, or decimal 10) or:

```
    id.sendcontrol('m')
```

to send a Carriage Return (which is control-m, or decimal 13).

If those don't work then please explain exactly what does happen, and how that differs from what you wanted or expected to happen.

Comment: Hi ottomeister , thank you for your help I really appriciate it. Actually I am using pexpect a python module I read through the documentation and found sendcontrol. I tried it with sendline ('') but it didn't help. On the documentation it gave an example sendcontrol ('g') but it didn't explain what the g letter does and what kind of key code to look for.

Comment: You are a star thank you ottomeister, it worked perfectly! strange it worked with id.sendcontrol('m') j and d. if I may ask these letters j,m what exactly are they? Thank you so much again for your wonderful help. it couldnt of been answered any better.

Comment: This is not working on RHEL 7.5 for me.  I'm trying different combinations, but `sendcontrol('m')` did not work, despite being able to enter CTRL-M by hand in the terminal and get the expected CR.

Comment: For me, `send('\r\n')`, `sendline('\r\n')`, or any combination of `\r` and/or `\n` in those methods worked.  However, `sendcontrol('j')` never worked (in script or manually) and `sendcontrol('m')` works manually, but not in script.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to "press enter", you can send a newline:

```
id.send("\n")
```

As for other characters that you might want to use `sendcontrol()` with, I found this useful: https://condor.depaul.edu/sjost/lsp121/documents/ascii-npr.htm

For instance, I was interested in Ctrl+v.  Looking it up in the table shows this line:

| control character | python & java | decimal | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ^v | \x16 | 22 | synchronous idle |

So if I want to send that character, I can do any of these:

```py
id.send('\x16')
id.send(chr(22))
id.sendcontrol('v')
```

`sendcontrol()` just looks up the correct character to send and then sends it like any other text

For keys not listed in that table, you can run this script: https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/blob/master/tests/getch.py (ctrl space to exit)

For instance, ran that script and pressed `F4` and it said:

```
27<STOP>
79<STOP>
83<STOP>
```

So then to press F4 via pexpect:

```py
id.send(chr(27) + chr(79) + chr(83))
```