# How to send a variable to the command line in Python

Tags: python, linux, tkinter

I have a Python GUI written with `tkinter` which calls a second function upon a button press. This function then waits for an input, using `raw_input()` and then acts upon the result. i.e. the function is of the format:

```
DO THINGS
a = raw_input('Enter value: ')
if int(a) == 0:
    do this
elif int(a) == 1:
    do something else
```

From my GUI, I want to send the value (`0` or `1` or more options), such that the function continues to execute as I ask. I will do this with a button press in `tkinter`, but that's not important, the key is how to send this value to the command line.
I have looked at `subprocess.Popen` and `subprocess.communicate`:

[How to make python script press 'enter' when prompted on Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31535592/how-to-make-python-script-press-enter-when-prompted-on-shell)

and `Pexpect`:

[python pexpect sendcontrol key characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295550/python-pexpect-sendcontrol-key-characters)

However, I'm a relative novice with Python and Linux, and can't get these to work - perhaps they are correct but I just need a bit more of a specific answer for my work. I feel like this question should be very easy to solve, but I just can't find how to do it. I'd also rather work with built-in modules, so if it can be done without `Pexpect` that would be great - I think I'm right in saying this doesn't come as part of the initial Python installation.

Comment: Do you actually need the value your program sends to appear in the terminal? If not, it's probably better to keep it within Python. In that case you would replace `raw_input` with something else that checks for a value being sent from the button or from the terminal.

Comment: Can you modify the code for the function that calls `raw_input()`? If so, it's possible to set up a pipe that a subprocess will output to, that your python script can read from.

Comment: No I don't need the value to appear - I did wonder if there were better ways to communicate with the function - if this is possible and you have an example that would be great!

Comment: Ah I've just remembered/rediscovered that if I don't call raw_input() in my function, the GUI is frozen, as it waits for the return of the function - the way I got around this was by calling raw_input(), which seems to free up my GUI again - it seems this question has become more complicated than I first thought, and probably requires a different method for me calling the function in my GUI in the first place. Any suggestions would be helpful.